# Handling subdomains and https with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, subdomain

In the .htaccess example below, if someone types in a URL like the following...

http://mysite.com/ricks-motorcycles

...it will automatically load the page from x.com's subdirectory under public_html called "ricks-motorcycles". This technique is called *Proxy Throughput*.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ricks-motorcycles/(.*)$  http://x.com/ricks-motorcycles/$1 [P,L]
```

This is great, but how do I handle two other situations:

(1) Someone wanting https instead of http.

(2) Someone wanting...

http#//ricks-motorcycles.mysite.com/

...instead of...

http#//mysite.com/ricks-motorcycles/

(Switch # with : above because StackOverflow was blocking me from posting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can qualify your rewrites with a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ricks-motorcycles/(.*)$ https://example.com/ricks-motorcycles/$1 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =ricks-motorcycles.mysite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ricks-motorcycles/$1 [P,L]
```

For more information, see the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/).

Comment: Thanks, it's close enough to get me going.