# Make Codeigniter ignore directory

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have Codeigniter installed and working for my main site.

But I am now trying to add an add-on domain to the same hosting account, so I can have two sites running on the same hosting. Add-on domains make a new folder in the main public_html folder to store the web files.

How can I get Codeigniter to ignore this directory? The site doesn't load properly when I try and view it.

I have an SSL on the main site too and redirection for www URLS. Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (site|sections|here)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} onsite|sections|here)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054458/handling-subdomains-and-https-with-htaccess?rq=1 It may relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple domains on the same hosting two of which use CI. Don't change the main htaccess, only the one inside the folder containing the CI install. If your main site is directly in the public_html folder you may have to move it to it's own folder and redirect your URL to that folder, other than that this really shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: How do you redirect the URL to that folder?

Comment: It should be in your control panel. If you have cPanel it's under Domains -> Redirects. Choose the domain to redirect and point it to the correct folder.

Comment: When I try and do that I just get 404 errors every time I try and go to a page on the site. The main page loads OK though. Surely the SSL will stop working if the site is in a subfolder?

Comment: Plus I don't want to actually redirect the site. I don't want the folder of the CI install in the URL, it messes everything up and the site won't load.

Comment: That would be what the base url is for in the config and modify the htaccess to reflect the folder it's now in.