# Force SSL for eCommerce on Site

Tags: .htaccess

I have a series of subdomains like the following on my site:

```
site.website.com/shop
site2.website.com/shop
```

For all of my domains where I have my store I'd like this to be forced over SSL. Is there a wildcard for subdomains? How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling subdomains and https with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054458/handling-subdomains-and-https-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# force www for main site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# remove www for app site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(app\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+app[/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.domain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ app/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Would I need to replace any of domain or app with my domain name or subdomain or will this work for all variables?

Comment: You're going to have to change the app.domain.com stuff to yours.

Comment: Instead of app can I use * so it works for all my subdomains? I don't want to have to update this file for each new subdomain.

Comment: Why don't you try it?